# Anaconda Terminal error pywin32_bootstrap

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I got this error in my Anaconda Navigator base Terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywin32_bootstrap'

Remainder of file ignored
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I got the same error during `pip install`, and I solved it by installing build 225 of pywin32 instead of the latest version:

```
pip install pywin32==225
```

Answer (score 17):

I followed soberWolf's suggestion, but needed to add the --user switch as the permissions seem a little off, so `pip install --ignore-installed pywin32 --user`

Answer (score 4):

try `pip install --ignore-installed pywin32` to reinstall pywin32

quote: [How to fix 'ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612306/how-to-fix-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-win32api)