# is there any solution for kernel error in jupyter notebook(i installed jupyter notebook in mysystem)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1703, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 158, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 301, in start_kernel
    kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 248, in pre_start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 474, in write_connection_file
    kernel_name=self.kernel_name
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 138, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 435, in secure_write
    win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
  File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 361, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
    import win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
```

Comment: If you are new you can try using Anaconda or Miniconda environment. It handles most of the dependencies for you.

Comment: yes iam beginner, how can i try anaconda

Comment: you can download it from https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: no module named win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343774/importerror-no-module-named-win32api)

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32a"

[Python 3.6 install win32api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370339/python-3-6-install-win32api/42400980)

Comment: :\Users\DELL>pip install pywin32
Error processing line 7 of c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywin32.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywin32_bootstrap'

Remainder of file ignored
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (227)
it gave me this error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58989806/anaconda-terminal-error-pywin32-bootstrap