# DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found. win32api, sys, os

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I tried to convert .xls to .xlsx

this is my code:

```
import os
address = os.getcwd()
import win32com.client as win32

fname = address + "\\Bundles.xls"
fname2 = address + "\\searchresults.xls"
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel2 = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname)
wb5 = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname2)

wb.SaveAs(fname+"x", FileFormat = 51)
wb5.SaveAs(fname2+"x", FileFormat = 51)    #FileFormat = 51 is for .xlsx extension
wb.Close()
wb5.Close()                               #FileFormat = 56 is for .xls extension
excel.Application.Quit()
excel2.Application.Quit()
print('File .xls convert .xlsx successful!!')
```

Then I got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\shenshuaic\Desktop\SFP Program\win32test.py", line 10, in <module>
    import win32com.client as win32
  File "C:\Users\shenshuaic\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have already reinstall pywin32. It is still happen

Answer (score 3):

The traceback indicates that the problem actually occurs when importing win32api. I had the same issue while trying to import win32api directly (rather than importing win32.client). This answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60611014/7520085

*(...) After copied the two files from Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32 to C:\Windows\System32, it works.
(...) The two files are pythoncom38.dll and pywintypes38.dll.*

Comment: From an administrator prompt, go to the python `Scripts` directory, and run `python -B pywin32_postinstall.py`

Comment: ALSO: if you have multiple `venv`'s with different versions of _pywin32_, the _Import Error_ will come right back when you switch the `venv`.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from DLLs from pywin32 not being put in the right place during the installation process.

Running this in the anaconda prompt helped me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pywin32
```

Comment: it doesn't work bro
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
 PS C:\Users\shenshuaic> C:/Users/shenshuaic/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/python.exe "c:/Users/shenshuaic/Desktop/SFP Program/SFP.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/shenshuaic/Desktop/SFP Program/SFP.py", line 10, in <module>
    import win32com.client as win32
  File "c:\Users\shenshuaic\Desktop\SFP Program\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spyder and I initially tried:

```
conda install pywin32 
import win32com.client
```

But kept getting an error.
So I tried:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pywin32
```

and then

```
import win32com.client
```

It works perfectly.