# Issue creating conda environment in miniconda3

Tags: python, conda

I am trying to create a new environment in miniconda using the following

```
(base) C:\Users\User>conda create -n myenv python=3.10
```

But am getting the following error report:

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 87, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 84, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_create.py", line 21, in execute
        if is_conda_environment(context.target_prefix):
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 591, in target_prefix
        return determine_target_prefix(self)
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 1738, in determine_target_prefix
        return locate_prefix_by_name(prefix_name)
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 1681, in locate_prefix_by_name
        envs_dirs = context.envs_dirs
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 517, in envs_dirs
        return mockable_context_envs_dirs(self.root_writable, self.root_prefix, self._envs_dirs)
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 91, in mockable_context_envs_dirs
        fixed_dirs += join(user_data_dir(APP_NAME, APP_NAME), 'envs'),
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 67, in user_data_dir
        path = os.path.join(_get_win_folder(const), appauthor, appname)
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 284, in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32
        from win32com.shell import shellcon, shell
    ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shell: The specified procedure could not be found.

`$ C:\Users\User\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py create -n myenv python=3.10`

  environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
```

I have recently installed miniconda but thought I would see if there is any updates that are causing the issues so I ran

```
(base) C:\Users\User>conda update conda
```

And got a similar error:

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 87, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 84, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_update.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'update')
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 260, in install
        unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 152, in solve_for_transaction
        unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 195, in solve_for_diff
        final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 300, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 463, in _collect_all_metadata
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 1058, in _prepare
        reduced_index = get_reduced_index(self.prefix, self.channels,
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 288, in get_reduced_index
        new_records = SubdirData.query_all(spec, channels=channels, subdirs=subdirs,
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 118, in query_all
        create_cache_dir()
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 876, in create_cache_dir
        cache_dir = join(PackageCacheData.first_writable().pkgs_dir, 'cache')
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 151, in first_writable
        pkgs_dirs = context.pkgs_dirs
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 530, in pkgs_dirs
        fixed_dirs += user_data_dir(APP_NAME, APP_NAME),
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 67, in user_data_dir
        path = os.path.join(_get_win_folder(const), appauthor, appname)
      File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 284, in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32
        from win32com.shell import shellcon, shell
    ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shell: The specified procedure could not be found.

`$ C:\Users\User\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py update conda`

  environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
```

I am an R user so not familiar with Python but to me, this suggests that there is something wrong with my install.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61382692/anaconda-navigator-cannot-launch-from-win32com-shell-import-shellcon-shell) any help?

Comment: @w08r Yes! Thanks, it worked using ```pip install pywin32==300``` as mentioned by @93Ramadan

Answer (score 0):

The answer comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61382692/anaconda-navigator-cannot-launch-from-win32com-shell-import-shellcon-shell) as suggested by @w08r

Posting here in case anyone else finds this post first. Install an older version on win32.com:

`pip install pywin32==300`

For some reason

```
pip install pywin32==301
```

doesn't work for me, similar to mentioned in the comments in linked answer.