# Jupyter Notebook - kernel not starting

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Python 3.7.8 and jupyter 6.1.3, and for some reason I'm not able to get Jupyter notebook to start. I'm able to connect to notebook and navigate through folders, but when I attempt to open a .ipynb file, I receive the following error:

```
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Uninstalling and reinstalling pywin32 doesn't appear to fix the problem. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58612306/2996989) question answers, it may solve your issue

Comment: Did you try `pip install win32api==224` because 225 version have many [problems](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1406)