# disconnection error while loading tensorflow in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I've been examining the following error:

```
Connection failed error 
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api,
```

It comes up whenever I try to load the kernel that refers to my environment with tensorflow installed inside jupyter notebook. It gives a disconnection error in the notebook.

I've tried `Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install` in an Admin command prompt, but the prompt states it cannot find the specified path. `'Het systeem kan het opgegeven pad niet vinden.'`

I've read somewhere to copy `C:\Users\nicol\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0-Adm\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32` to `C:\Windows\System32`. I manually copied this file, but this did not resolve the issue.

I keep getting the following error:

```sh
File "C:\Users\nicol\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0-Adm\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 387, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: Kan opgegeven procedure niet vinden.

Kan opgegeven procedure niet vinden is Dutch for The specified module could not be found. Literally it is translated as The specified procedure could not be found.
```

What could be a solution here?

Comment: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1431#issuecomment-548584385

Comment: Could you please refer to the answers in this issue.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612306/how-to-fix-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-win32api/63102942#63102942