# I have a issue when run "locust -V"

Tags: winapi, locust

I got this error
from win32api import STD_INPUT_HANDLE
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

Comment: Are you maybe using miniconda? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612306/how-to-fix-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-win32api

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1646:

```
pip uninstall pywin32 
conda install pywin32
```

Or you could try this: (found here https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1174)

```
conda install -c anaconda pywin32
```