# How to fix console error on Spyder when changing the Anaconda environment

Tags: anaconda, spyder

Very new to this so I would like to apologize if I am not properly asking questions in the correct format.

I am trying to use spyder on anaconda, not on the root environment.

When I load spyder in the base(root) it works fine.  But someone told me you should never run in the root and create an to create an environment when doing any work.

So when I created the new environment and load up Spyder I get an error on the console:

The error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\andre_vclze7t\anaconda3\envs\py3912\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 1568, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle,
File "C:\Users\andre_vclze7t\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 309, in start_kernel
kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)
File "C:\Users\andre_vclze7t\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 258, in pre_start_kernel
self.write_connection_file()
File "C:\Users\andre_vclze7t\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 468, in write_connection_file
self.connection_file, cfg = write_connection_file(self.connection_file,
File "C:\Users\andre_vclze7t\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 138, in write_connection_file
with secure_write(fname) as f:
File "C:\Users\andre_vclze7t\anaconda3\envs\py3912\lib\contextlib.py", line 119, in **enter**
return next(self.gen)
File "C:\Users\andre_vclze7t\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 461, in secure_write
win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
File "C:\Users\andre_vclze7t\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 387, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: I was able to fix it by creating the conda environment from python 3.7 but testing it at 3.9 twice I get the same situation.

Comment: Also VS code worked in every situation.

Comment: Maybe this could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612306/how-to-fix-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-win32api

Comment: looked at the link and added pywin32 but same issue.  Python 3.7 works fine and for now that is ok.  Now I am just curious as to what is causing it.  I will keep up the hunt.

Comment: Oh I see, and what about creating a new env using only packages from the conda-forge channel?