# How can I fix this Anaconda issue?

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5, anaconda

[Anaconda navigator will not open because of an import error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZuUz.png)

I tried searching for solutions but nothing has worked so far. I updated anaconda and reinstalled it and that did not work. After I initially installed Anaconda, I created a virtual environment in PyCharm and then both programs actually stopped working. There seems to be a file in PyQt5 that is lacking permissions but I am not sure how to solve that problem or troubleshoot.

Image is embedded in the link. It says " File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtCore.py", line 15, in 
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: Access is denied."

Comment: Have you tried any of [these...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612306/how-to-fix-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-win32api)?

Comment: yes but none of it worked for me.

Comment: Was Anaconda installed for the current user (preferable) or as the Administrator?

Comment: as current user